# Memory-efficient alternative to LookupOp for coloring a two-colors image?

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, awt

Given a white and black image, no grey (in ARGB: `0xFFFFFFFF` and `0xFF000000`), I want to colorize the black in a specific color and the white in another specific color.

I currently use the following code to that end:

```
    private LookupOp createLookupOp(Color foreground, Color background) {
        var lookupTable = new byte[4][256];

        var fg = foreground.getRGB();
        Arrays.fill(lookupTable[0], (byte) (fg >> 16));
        Arrays.fill(lookupTable[1], (byte) (fg >> 8));
        Arrays.fill(lookupTable[2], (byte) (fg));
        Arrays.fill(lookupTable[3], (byte) (fg >> 24));

        var bg = background.getRGB();
        lookupTable[0][0] = (byte) (bg >> 16);
        lookupTable[1][0] = (byte) (bg >> 8);
        lookupTable[2][0] = (byte) (bg);
        lookupTable[3][0] = (byte) (bg >> 24);

        return new LookupOp(new ByteLookupTable(0, lookupTable), null);
    }
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
var lookup = lookups.computeIfAbsent(colorPair, colors -> createLookupOp(colors.foreground, colors.background));
var coloredImage = lookup.filter(originalImage, null);
graphics2d.drawImage(coloredImage, originalWidth, originalHeight, null);
```

And it does the job. But I'm questioning this process because it uses a huge amount of memory (at least 1kb per color pair), and it's rather slow to create when I have thousands of mini images I need to draw in different colors.

To speed things up, I store the result in a map, but even so, I still have like 200,000 items in my map at the end of the application run, and that's roughly 200 MB that are stored in my map.

I'd like to know if there's a cheap and fast alternative to this `LookupOp`.

Comment: If your input B/W images are using a 1 bit/two color `IndexColorModel`, you could at least make the filter part a lot faster by just replacing the `IndexColorModel` (reusing the `WritableRaster`).

Comment: @HaraldK This seems promising and certainly worth an answer. How would that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more detailed version of my idea outlined in the comments, assuming the B/W images are 1 bit images with `IndexColorModel` (if they are not, they can be converted, of course). Given this, we can just swap the palette or `IndexColorModel`, to have the image instantly re-colored.

Code will look something like this:

```java
// The original B/W image
IndexColorModel blackAndWhite = new IndexColorModel(1, 2, new int[] {0x000000, 0xFFFFFF}, 0, false, -1, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
BufferedImage bwImage = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, blackAndWhite);

// A new color pair
Color red = Color.RED;
Color blue = Color.BLUE;

// Create a palette from the color pair
IndexColorModel redAndBlue = new IndexColorModel(1, 2, new int[] {red.getRGB(), blue.getRGB()}, 0, false, -1, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

// And finally a new two-colored image from the original image, using the new palette
BufferedImage rbImage = new BufferedImage(redAndBlue, bwImage.getRaster(), reaAndBlue.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

Now, both images share raster, so a change in one will also change the other. This is extremely cheap, memory- and CPU-wise. However, if this is not desired, you can replace `bwImage.getRaster()` with `bwImage.copyData(null)` on the last line, to create a "detached" copy.

You can also cache the `IndexColorModel`s for each pair of colors, like you do with the `LookupOp`s above, but I'm not sure if that's worth it (depends on how often you reuse the color pairs).

Comment: Yes, it works great, thank you! I don't even need to store anything with this as it's much faster. That's great!